# Parametrization of a sphere

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to argue geometrically that mapping the point $(u,v,0)$ to $(x,y,z)$ gives a parametrization of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ minus the north pole. My questions are:

a) What exactly is a geometrical argument? Like, how should one go to give a geometrical argument?

b) When it says the mapping gives a parametrization, is it referring to the line created by joining $(u,v,0)$ and $(x,y,z)$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A parametrization of a surface is a way to describe every point of that surface using two parameters. The term "geometrical argument" is not very precise and just means that your reasoning should be geometrical rather than, say, purely using algebra. I suspect that some algebra is going to be involved at some point, though. I'd like to observe that "mapping $(u,v,0)$ to $(x,y,z)$" does not in itself mean anything. Where are you mapping, say $(2,1,0)$ under this scheme?

Answer (score 1):

Sit the sphere on the plane.  Center at $(0,0,1)$, North Pole at $(0,0,2)$.
Draw a line from $(u,v,0)$ to the North Pole; it will cut the sphere at one other point.

Answer (score 1):

A line containing the north pole, not tangent to sphere,  will intersect the sphere once in, let's say M point and the plane $z=0$ in one point P(u, v, 0). The association P -> M will give you the mapping. The only point that cannot be mapped this way is the north pole.